# UILabel doesn't show at the center on iOS Simulator (Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, uilabel, xcode6

I'm doing a tutorial where I have to change a label's text.

On the storyboard, I align my label's center, but when running on iOS simulator it goes to the bottom right.

I think it's because of the device that is set? On this tutorial it says to set to retina iPhone, but I can't find it.

I have iPhone 4s, 5, 6, and 6 plus, and and some iPads.

Can someone help me?

Comment: disable size classes in file inspector and try.....learn more about size classes

Comment: Trying right now thanks

Comment: Worked! Thanks researching for size classes and auto layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about Auto Layout and more specifically how to set constraints so that your `UILabel` is at the center of any device running on iOS Simulator.

There is Ray's [Video Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64392/video-tutorial-beginning-auto-layout) on Auto Layout and the [Beginning Auto Layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) blog post for iOS 7. Maybe you give the rich Apple documentation a chance: [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1)